# iOS: How to draw a speical shape

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

How to draw the shape shown below using UIBezierPath or CG? I can think of several ways, but none are very good. It contains a small arrow/triangle and a circle. Also I need to be able to rotate this shape, so the angle of the arrow can not be hard coded. You can ignore the background light grey circle. Just the red shape (plus a UILabel is better)

[image: Example image showing the desired shape]

Comment: http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path/

Comment: @Wingzero did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, subclass `UIView` and override `drawRect:`. This code is really close and should get you there with some tweaking:

```
//Get the graphics context
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

//Colors, I was a little off here
let color = UIColor(red: 0.880, green: 0.653, blue: 0.653, alpha: 1.000)

//The circle
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(86, 31, 58, 56))
color.setFill()
ovalPath.fill()


//The pointed arrow on the left of the circle
var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(87, 54))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(76, 60))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(87, 66))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(87, 54))
color.setFill()
bezierPath.fill()


//Now, draw the 17%
let textRect = CGRectMake(95, 45, 40, 29)
var textTextContent = NSString(string: "17%")
let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

//Text components
let textFontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle]

let textTextHeight: CGFloat = textTextContent.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(textRect.width, CGFloat.infinity), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textFontAttributes, context: nil).size.height
CGContextSaveGState(context)
CGContextClipToRect(context, textRect);
textTextContent.drawInRect(CGRectMake(textRect.minX, textRect.minY + (textRect.height - textTextHeight) / 2, textRect.width, textTextHeight), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
CGContextRestoreGState(context)
```

All of that gives you this:

Comment: I ended up writing my own view and a dataSource delegate for it to draw it. Though I cannot post all my code, but it does similar to your solution

Comment: I would like to point out that drawing text in drawRect: may seem like a quick and easy way to do it, but this has implications, for example it can not be picked up by the accessibility tools in iOS, i.e VoiceOver would not see this text. So I would advise against drawing the text yourself and using a subview instead, a simple UILabel with the text on it should do the trick.